Email config error
I install module from https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app, I config stmp.gmail then username using my email for sure, password is my app password like a key, then i click test but is not work, not loading anything. How can i fix ?

when i click that doesn't have any request send to server, i think some js file not work

when i saw log


which magento version you are using?

I'm using 2.4.6, when i run bin/magento static-content:deploy is not compile js file that handle click event, I dont know how to fix. I just create new 2.4.6 magento project then it works fine
